# Are there hidden events?

Tags: probability

Consider the sample space S = {a, b, c, d} and a probability function Pr : *S* ->**R** on S. Define the events A = {a}, B = {a, b}, C = {a, b, c}, and D = {b, d}. You are given
that Pr(A) = 1/10, Pr(B) = 1/2, and Pr(C) = 7/10.
What is Pr(D)?

For this question, I think the answer should be 1-(sum of the probabilities of A,B and C). Should I account for events not shown? And if so, how do I do that? I asked because the number of events should be 2^4.

Comment: Well yes you should account for the events not show... What if they had given you the probability of no event at all?

Comment: For discrete probability, if you have a sample space with $n$ elements, then there are $2^n$ events: one for each possible subset of the sample space. In this case, you are given only three out of the $16$ events, so you can't conclude the probability of the fourth event directly. Instead you need to use the given probabilities to calculate $p_a$, $p_b$, $p_c$ and $p_d$ where these are the probabilities of the events $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{c\}$ and $\{d\}$ respectively. Note that, for example, the probability of the event $C = \{a, b, c\}$ is $p_a + p_b + p_c$, by additivity.

Comment: So the solution will be to get *Pb* from Pr(B) and use that to get *Pc* from Pr(C). Then, get number of d's by subtracting the sum of a, b and c from 10. Is that right?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR my question above this, please?

Comment: @Manuel: That's correct. (And after finding $p_d$, you need to find $P(D) = P(\{b, d\})$.)

Comment: @Manuel: By the way, if you work out the answer, feel free to post it here. That way anyone can point out if you have made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the best at explanations but here goes:

*Pr(B)*= *Pa*+ *Pb*

*Pb* = 1/2 - 1/10

```
    =2/5
```

Pr(C) =*Pa* + *Pb* + *Pc*

*Pc* = 7/10 - (1/10+ 2/5)

```
    = 1/5
```

*Pd* = 1 - *Pa* - *Pb* - *Pc*

```
 =3/10
```

So, *Pr(D)* = *Pb* + *Pd*

```
         = 4/10 + 3/10 

         = 7/10
```

P.S. feel free free to edit this answer, as long it is the correct answer

Comment: Thanks!... I will correct the typo

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
$$\Pr(D)=1+\Pr(B)-\Pr(C)-\Pr(A)$$
Hint:
$$
D=\{b\}\cup\{d\}\qquad\{d\}=S\setminus C\qquad\{b\}=B\setminus A$$

Comment: How did you arrive by that formula?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!